# Understanding the geometric distribution

Tags: probability

It's a simple question that has to do with the interpretation of the geometric distribution and frequency function:

$P (X=k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p $ for $k = 1,2,3\ldots $ where we are interpreting $X$ as being up to and including the first success.

So i was looking at a frequency function of this distribution with regards to winning a certain lottery. It showed the distribution as the number of tickets a person must purchase up to and including the winning ticket.

The graph was asymptotic in the sense that the probability of winning started out large, but the more tickets one purchased the probability would approach 0.

This is where i am confused because just thinking about it i would have thought that one's probability of success would go up with more tickets purchased. Or is this a scenario where my intuition is leading me astray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the **cumulative** distribution function $P(X\leq k)$ in order to approximately represent the quantity you are interested in, i.e., winning in up to $k+1$ tickets. I say approximately since the geometric models sampling without replacement, but for this case of large n (say ${49 \choose 6}$) and tiny $p=1/n$ it doesn't matter.

Comment: Then what is the graph that i described above trying to explain?

Comment: It explains the probability of the first success occuring in exactly $k$ trials. Since you can't directly mechanize $k$ trials [k tickets] without mechanizing 1,2,..,k-1 trials [if you buy k tickets, you've already bought k-t tickets for any t=1,..,k-1] you need the cumulative distribution.

Answer (score 1):

> So I was looking at a frequency function of this distribution with regards to winning a certain lottery. It showed the distribution as the number of tickets a person must purchase up to and including the winning ticket. The graph was asymptotic in the sense that the probability of winning started out large, but the more tickets one purchased the probability would approach 0.

Ah.  It sounds like the graph is not of $P(X\leq k)$ (the cumulative distribution) but of $P(X=k)$, the probability mass function.    This is plotting the probability of winning with *exactly* $k$ tickets.

Ref: [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)