# Explanation of Geometric Distribution Graph

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I understand what the geometric distribution is and that it is calculating the probability of the number of trials needed up to and including the first success. Expressed as the following:

$$P(X = k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p$$

I asked a similar question years ago and for the life of me I still cannot wrap my head around the interpretation of the graph from the example:

[image]

What I mean by not wrapping my head around the interpretation is for example, let's choose $x = 10$. What I'm interpreting in my mind is "the probability of winning the lottery after purchasing 10 tickets is roughly 0.19". But this cannot be right to me. Interpreting it in this fashion alludes to purchasing more tickets should mean a higher probability of winning the lottery. This is what would be the case if I was thinking of the CDF, but I'm not. So what is the way to interpret the PMF of the geometric distribution in this example?

Question that I asked previously:   [Understanding the geometric distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410888/understanding-the-geometric-distribution)

Comment: You might want to include a link to the question you asked years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability $P(X=10)$ is the probability of needing to buy exactly 10 tickets in order for the 10th ticket to be your *first* winner.  Put another way, it's the probability of buying 9 losing tickets in a row before buying your first winning ticket.

If it helps, consider the similar experiment of flipping a coin until the first head.  The probability that the very first toss gives a head is $P(Y=1)=1/2$.   The probability $P(Y=2)$ represents the probability of *failing* to get heads on your first toss (probability 1/2) and then *furthermore* succeeding in getting heads on your second toss.  That's probability 1/2 to first fail followed by probability 1/2 to then success, for an overall probability of $P(Y=2)=1/2  * 1/2 = 1/4$.  Similarly, to get $P(Y=3)$, you have to fail twice (probability $1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4$) and then *furthermore* succeed on your third toss (probability $1/2$), for a total probability of $P(Y=3)=1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/8$.

The decreasing probabilities in both the lottery and coin examples result from the fact that, for example, $P(Y=10)$ needs 9 failures (and it's tough to lose so many times!) before you get your first success on the tenth try.

Comment: I think your explanation finally made it click for me....I think a big part of the problem I was having with this example was I was associating the probability of winning the lottery in the example: $p = \frac{1}{9}$, with the probability of winning the lottery in real life $p = \frac{1}{\text{big number}}$. So since the probability in real life is already so small, now it makes sense why if it took "10 tries" to get a success why that would be the case.....Ah finally!!!! After all these years....SMH...

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation is correct: $(1-p)^{k-1}p$ is the probability of first success on the $k$th independent attempt.

The problem lies in the statement *more tickers should mean a higher probability of winning the lottery*:

You are raising the power $k-1\; (>1)$ of a fraction $(1-p)$. As the power increases (i.e. you purchase more tickets), the value $(1-p)^{k-1}$ decreases for a fixed value of $p$.

Comment: Purchasing more tickets does mean a higher probability of winning the lottery. I am aware that $0<p<1$ and the product of them will become smaller. Hence whay I'm trying to reconcile how I should be interpreting things.

Comment: What you have in mind is a situation where the choice of buying tickets ($X$) changes the probability of winning $p$. In this case, you don't have a geometric distribution (where the parameter $p$ is fixed). 

One way to think of it is as follows: You as a buyer of tickets is a very small player in the gambling market (no matter how many tickets you buy) . The probability of success is determined in this large market and your choice can't really affect the market outcome. This is a classic interpretation of **competitive markets** that economists use.

Comment: So  building on that idea to see if I'm interpreting the geometric correctly. The probabilities are fixed because of how large the lotto market is, so then what is "success on the tenth trial" mean in this scenario?